# Check if opened filename exists in database

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm inserting rows into a database, and I need to check if such a file was uploaded already.

```
String filename = fileopen.getSelectedFile().getName();
String fileNameDB = "select File_name from dbo.Table";
if (fileNameDB.equalsIgnoreCase(filename)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File exists", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
} else {
    //inserting code
}
```

But it's not showing an error, and goes straight to insert.

Comment: What do you expect `String fileNameDB = "select File_name from dbo.Table";` to do?

Comment: Return all filenames from database?

Comment: @n0rek All `String fileNameDB = "select File_name from dbo.Table";` does is assign the literal string `"select File_name from dbo.Table"` to a variable.

Comment: @n0rek I think you'll find it just creates a `String` literal of `"select File_name from dbo.Table"`. So your condition is actually `if ("select File_name from dbo.Table".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName))`You need to actually query the database using whatever library you have decided to use.

Comment: Oh right, so result set etc. :) Thank you.