# Check if chosen file exists in database using checksum

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm using checksum to check if choosen file already been inserted to database.
Inserting works fine but I can't manage to check this exist.

I'm using such code:

```
            String fileName = fileopen.getSelectedFile().getName();
            String checksumDB = "select top 1 Checksum from dbo.Szyby where Checksum = ?";
            MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            String checksum = getFileChecksum(md5Digest, fileopen.getSelectedFile());
            PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(checksumDB);
            prep.setString(1, checksum);
            ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
            if (rs.getInt(1) > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dublowanie", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

Comment: You probably want to query for `select count() from dbo.Table where checksum = ?`, using the calculated checksum as parameter. Then check if `rs.getInt(1)>0`.

Comment: How does the code when inserting to database look like? What value does rs.getString(1) have?

Comment: Why did you create a new question for the exact same thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666832/check-if-opened-filename-exists-in-database

Comment: It's not the same thing, here it's a checksum.

Comment: Conceptually it is the same thing. The challenge is that neither question is very clear. What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I'm struggling with check if checksum of opened file already exists in column in Table.

Comment: Getting the checksum of the new file? Finding it in the table? What part isn't working?

Comment: Getting checksum of the new file works fine, only finding it in the table is not.

Comment: Did you figure that part out in your other question? It is the same thing here.

Comment: No I did not. I decided to verify checksum instead filename and gues I'm strucked in the same spot but with other code.

Comment: Instead of pulling back the entire table you should try to select ONLY the row with the new checksum. You do that by adding a parameterized where clause to your query. Then if you have a row you found it, otherwise it isn't there.

Comment: OK great...so it is working now?

Comment: I have edited my question and now I'm getting "result set has no current row" error

Comment: Then that means you didn't find the row. That means the checksum is not in the table.

Comment: Well but it is in the table :)
I even removed parameter from where clause and used checksum variable, then when debugging it returns: select top 1 Checksum from dbo.Table where Checksum = 'fd5b149d60b9332b27b08fa2334276ed' and that checksum is in the table

Comment: Then you need to evaluate the query you are passing to sql server. You can use a sql trace for this easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried primitive solution without PreparedStatement and using while loop and it works.

Here's the code:

```
            try {
            String fileName = fileopen.getSelectedFile().getName();
            MessageDigest md5Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            String checksum = getFileChecksum(md5Digest, fileopen.getSelectedFile());
            Statement prep = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery("select top 1 Checksum from dbo.Table where Checksum = '" + checksum + "'");
            if (rs.next()){
                conn.rollback();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Already Exists", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
              //Inserting
            conn.commit();            
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
```

I believe it can be used with Autocommit true. Still I don't know why `rs.next()` returns result but `rs.getString(1)` does not but most important it works.